# Factoring try catch

Tags: java

I have a Java EE application with dozens of web services using the same pattern:

```
public Response myWebService1() {
    try {
        // do something different depending on the web service called
    } catch (MyCustomException e1) {
        return Response.status(409).build();
    } catch (UnauthorizedException e2) {
        return Response.status(401).build();
    } catch (Exception e3) {
        return Response.status(500).build();
    }
}
```

Is that possible to factorize this piece of code?

Comment: Either do this, `catch (MyCustomerException | UnauthorizedException error) { /* Exception login to check what happened */ }` otherwise, keep doing what you are doing as you are returning error based on error type.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: it creates duplicate exception handling code when he needs different code at the comment

Comment: Are they all being called within the same method?

Comment: Try using AOP ideas / tools - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Comment: +1 for recognizing this in your code. Recommended book: Clean Code by Robert C. Martin. Explains exactly stuff like this. Single Responsibility Pattern (SRP), Separation of Concerns (SoC) and error handling is a concern.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If this is a JAX-RS environment, see [Tunaki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41570278/157247), handling this is specifically catered for and wonderfully simple.

If not:

You can have a functional interface accepting a function that can throw exceptions and returns a `Response`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Responder {
    Response handleRequest() throws Exception;
}
```

(As [Dici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3895960/dici) points out, you could make that a generic `ThrowingSupplier` or similar, since you're allowing it to throw `Exception`.)

Then have a helper method accepting an instance of it:

```
private static Response respond(Responder responder) {
    try {
        return responder.handleRequest();
    } catch (MyCustomException e1) {
        return Response.status(409).build();
    } catch (UnauthorizedException e2) {
        return Response.status(401).build();
    } catch (Exception e3) {
        return Response.status(500).build();
    }
}
```

...and use it via a lambda:

```
public Response myWebService1() {
    return respond(() -> {
        // Do stuff here, return a Response or throw / allow throws on error
    });
}
```

Comment: But perhaps there's a Java EE middleware concept that could be applied instead, I have to admit not being au fait with current Java EE stuff.

Comment: Darn it, why can't I find a `java.util.function` class that accepts no args and returns `<R>`?

Comment: `Runnable` is not very appropriate because it does not allow the code inside the catch to throw any checked exception or to return a value. I would use a custom interface. Apart from that, this answer is my preferred solution, I would have posted it if it was not already there

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `Supplier` does it, but does not allow checked exceptions. I would use some kind of `ThrowingSupplier`.

Comment: @Dici: Thanks. It was only when I was editing to add an interface that I realized the exceptions would pretty much mean you'd need your own.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's patience. I now have my second cup of coffee. :-) I've made the answer a CW since it would have been rubbish without Thomas Weller, NewUser, Maroun Maroun, and Dici's help.

Answer (score 26):

Since this is in a JAX-RS context, there is a much better way, that does not rely on catching a lot of different exceptions: use an [`ExceptionMapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html). This is a built-in mechanism of JAX-RS 1.0 that translates an exception type into a proper `Response` object to send to the client.

In your case, you could have the following classes defined once in your application:

```
@Provider
public class UnauthorizedExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<UnauthorizedException> {
   public Response toResponse(UnauthorizedException e) {
      return Response.status(401).build();
   }
}
```

```
@Provider
public class MyCustomExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyCustomException> {
   public Response toResponse(MyCustomException e) {
      return Response.status(409).build();
   }
}
```

```
@Provider
public class CatchAllExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
   public Response toResponse(Exception e) {
      return Response.status(500).build();
   }
}
```

The [`@Provider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html) annotation tells the JAX-RS runtime to discover this class when scanning. This makes sure that, wherever in your code, if a `MyCustomException` is thrown (and not explicitly catched), a 409 response will be returned. The code in your application would simply become:

```
public Response myWebService1() {
    // do something, and don't catch anything; just care about the happy path
}
```

The exception hierarchy is correctly taken into account. If the application code throws a `MyCustomExceptionMapper`, JAX-RS will look for an exception mapper registered with that type, and will go up the super class if it can't find one: this way, there can be a catch-all exception mapper handling every other case.

Comment: Definitely the best solution in JAX-RS environment.

Answer (score 6):

If all methods handle exceptions the same way, you can extract the exception handling to an external method :

```
public static Response exceptionHandler (Exception exc)
{
    if (exc instanceof MyCustomException) {
        return Response.status(409).build();
    } else if (exc instanceof UnauthorizedException) {
        return Response.status(401).build();
    } else {
        return Response.status(500).build();
    }
}

public Response myWebService1() {
    try {
        // do something different depending on the web service called
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        return exceptionHandler(exc);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have rethrow the exception in the handler to manage in a try catch instead of using instanceof but that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @AxelH throwing an exception is not free. Also, it would be a horrible abuse of the `throw` statement. If `instanceof` is required, use `instanceof`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider isn't it the building of the exception instance that take time ? Basicly the `catch` works the same as instanceof so I would **guess ** this will take the same amount of time. So the catch is bit less verbose and should not impact the performance.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, that is possible. We have a solution that looks like:

```
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exceptionConverter.convertAndThrow(exception);
    }
```

to unify re-throwing of exceptions based on the exception caught.

So that exception converter is the one central place where we "switch" over the exception type and do what needs to be done. Of course, the central element here is: all your classes need the **exact same** handling for the incoming exceptions.

We even go one step further and allow a wild mix of potential "input causes", but we also have **extensive** unit tests to ensure that the conversion always gives the expected result.

Please note: my answer is just about refactoring those "catch" cascade. You can still turn to TJs solution; but keep in mind: that approach adds a certain bit of complexity by introducing that Runnable aspect.

Answer (score 2):

@T.J.Crowder's response is perfect. But for those who can't use Java 8, this is how to implement it with earlier version of Java:

The Responder interface:

```
public interface Responder {
    Response handleRequest() throws Exception;
}
```

The helper method:

```
private static Response respond(Responder responder) {
    try {
        return responder.handleRequest();
    } catch (MyCustomException e1) {
        return Response.status(409).build();
    } catch (UnauthorizedException e2) {
        return Response.status(401).build();
    } catch (Exception e3) {
        return Response.status(500).build();
    }
}
```

With an anonymous class instead of a lambda expression:

```
Response response = respond(new Responder() {
    @Override
    public Response handleRequest() throws Exception {
        ...
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
});
```